# Is there a CSS selector for an element with adjacent text?

Tags: css

Here's what I have:

```
<a class="button">
    <i class="fa fa-times" />Some button label
</a>
```

where the `<i class="fa fa-times" />` is a [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) icon.

This renders with the icon right next to the text, without any space between them.

I was just adding a `margin-right` to the `i.fa` elements, but now I'm in a position where I need to add a button *without* any text, and the icon is off-center.

I considered `i.fa + span` to apply a `margin-left` to the text, but that would require me wrapping the text in a `span` (and there are a fair number of them sprinkled throughout my code).

I'm doing this in React components and I'd prefer to just update my stylesheets to handle this. If there's no CSS solution, then I'm going to write a Button component to handle it.

**Is there a selector which would allow me to select only those `i.fa` which have text adjacent to them, so I can apply a `margin-right` and space them out a bit?**

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such selector in CSS yet (AFAIK). As a workaround, I'd suggest setting something like `display:inline-grid; grid-column-gap:.5em` to the `.button` — it would add gap between icon and text only if there are both. Also, I hope your example is something like prepocessor code, since `<i />` is treated as unclosed tag in HTML.

Comment: As a heads up, I don't think the `<i />` tag is self closing...

Comment: Yeah, the `<i />` tag is a little weird. I grabbed this from a React component written in JSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option is to wrap the text in a `span` tag as you've suggested. You can't target text nodes with CSS.

Comment: Although I was sorely tempted to select @biziclop's answer, this one is probably more in line with the CSS specifications and is what I wound up doing.

Comment: @Kryten: You made the right choice. But it was a nice challenge.

Answer (score 0):

All is not lost: https://jsfiddle.net/47L4ajgd/

```css
.fa {
  display: inline; /* NOT inline-block! */
}

i::after {
  content: ' '; /* the word spacing itself */
  font-size: 0px;
  word-spacing: 50px; /* set this instead of margin */
}

/* Some styling for demo */
.fa-times::before {
  content: "ICON"; /* Font Not-So-Awesome */
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<a class="button">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>Some button label
</a>
<a class="button">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
</a>
<a class="button">
    Some button label
</a>
```